# By JQuery, how to specify on function as onClick handler for many radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function called `handleOnClickRadio(i, j);` and lots of radio buttons named as `id="something-radio[i][j]"`. All these radio buttons are in a table called "bigtable".

How could I attach the function `handleOnClickRadio()` to all these radio buttons? And call it correct with `handleOnClickRadio(i,j)`.

Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for editing How could I mark code quickly in Stackoverflow.com? Is there a shortcut available?

Comment: Mark the text that should be code and click the `{}` button. Or directly enclose inline code in backticks `\``. Code blocks should be indented by four spaces. See the editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not attach the click handler to the buttons at all. You say you have lots of them. Attaching the same event handler to each of them is a waste of memory and could even be a performance problem.
Use [*event delegation*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$('#tableID').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'click', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Then you could extract the `i` and `j` via regular expression (you could also consider to change the pattern so that you can use something simpler like [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)):

```
var exp = new RegExp("\\[(.+?)\\]\\[(.+?)\\]", 'g');
var match = exp.exec(this.id);
var i = match[1];
var j = match[2];
```

You could put this together like so:

```
$('#tableID').delegate('input[type=radio]', 'click', function() {
    var match = this.id.match(/\[(.+?)\]\[(.+?)\]/)
    var i = match[1]; // use parseInt(match[1]) if you need an integer
    var j = match[2];
    handleOnClickRadio(i,j);
});
```

<sub>*edit:* Made code a bit simpler.</sub>

If `i` and `j` correspond to column and row indicies, see [@Caspar Kleijne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861301/by-jquery-how-to-specify-on-function-as-onclick-handler-for-many-radio-buttons/4861419#4861419) for an alternative way to retrieve them.

For accessibility, you should consider binding the handler to the `change` event. Then changes via the keyboard will be recognized too.

Answer (score 2):

wire up the event like this

```
 $("#bigtable input[type='radio']").bind("click", OnClickRadio);
```

and use the handler like

```
 var OnClickRadio = function () {
    var col =  $(this).parent("td").index();
    var row =  $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").index(); 
        handleOnClickRadio(col, row)
 });
```

Comment: @David that would trigger the event twice...?

Comment: @Caspar, ahh...yes. It would indeed. Consider my suggestion rescinded =/ My previous suggestion, for historical reasons: I'd suggest adding the 'change' event, too: $("#bigtable input[type='radio']").bind("click change", OnClickRadio);.

Comment: @Caspar If I have a <th> in the table, what is value returned by ("td").index()? Is the index always staring from 0? How about without using a <tr> tag for table head instead of <th>?

Comment: @jcadam: Do you want to get the index including or excluding the header? In any way, if the header rows are fixed, there should be no problem to add or subtract that number.

Comment: I want the index including the header. The row index of head should be 0, and the row index of first data line should be 1, I guess.

Comment: @jcadam: `index()` returns the position relativ to it's siblings. So if you have `thead` and `tbody` then you would have to add `1` if you have one header row. If you don't have `thead` it should be fine. Just try and see what you get. If you only add `[i][j]` to the ID because of this, then @Caspar's method is the preferred way imho. It makes the whole structure easier to understand.

Comment: Btw +1 from me for the way to get the indices (that is the least I can do if I even refer to your answer in mine ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an onClick method to a collection of radio buttons within a table with a simple bit of jQuery. When you say 'table called "bigtable"', I'm assuming that you mean that it has id="bigtable" in the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bigtable input:radio").click(function() {
    // Your on click code here
  });
});
```

However, I would usually give each of the radio buttons a specific class using class="magicRadioButton" and then your jQuery code becomes a little clearer and doesn't rely on all of those radio buttons being within a table;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".magicRadioButton").click(function() {
    // Your on click code here
  });
});
```

Now, if you need to then plug this information into your current handleOnClickRadio method, you can do so with the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bigtable input:radio").click(function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var re = new RegExp("\\[(.*?)\\]\\[(.*)\\]");
    var matches = re.exec(button_id);

    var i = matches[1];
    var j = matches[2];
    handleOnClickRadio(i,j);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your expression should look like `"\\\[(.*?)\\]\\\[(.*)\\\]"`. In the string you need double backslash to escape regular expression characters and you have to make at least the first quantifier non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Felix, I'll update the original answer now. For some reason, I had it in my head that JS regex was non-greedy by default. As for the backslashes, I was just being dopey!

Answer (score 0):

Give them class names in conjunction with `$(this)` in your click trigger

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd have a onclick assigned to the big table rather than each and every radio button. Events in JavaScript bubble up so the table (which is the eventual parent of all these radio buttons) will receiving the event.

So in jQuery you would have code like this

```
$('#bigtable').click(handleOnClickRadio);
```

The signature of your handleOnClickRadio function would be

```
function handleOnClickRadio(evt) {    
   var radio = evt.target;
   var id = $(radio).attr('id'); 
}
```

evt.target will identify the actual radio button that was clicked/checked and you can access other attributes of the radio as well. such as

```
$(radio).attr('id)
```

Will give you the id of the radio button.

Comment: @Flix, thanks for editing - I was struggling with the editor to try and get it to format the code correctly, but nothing I did would work

Comment: You're welcome :) To format code, you have to intend each line with four spaces (or mark the code and click the `{}` button).

Comment: @Felix, I was doing that (selecting the code and then clicking on the tool bar button for code highlighting), but it kept mering lines and it wouldn't color highlight the code.

Comment: You clicked the wrong button, the citation button `“`. That happens to me often enough ;) You can see in the edit history, that your code was preceded with `>` which indicate citation.

Comment: @Felix: Yup, that was it! duh!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" class="many-radio-buttons" ....
```

jQuery:

```
$('.many-radio-buttons').click(function() {
  //your_code;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using delegate if you have lot of radios: that way, only one Event listener will be attached

see http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$("#globalContainer").delegate("input", "click", function(){
    //Perform a string test / regex to test if the id matches something-radio[i][j]
    //With a regex with capturing groups you can retrieve [i] and [j] values at the same time    
    if ( test($(this).attr("id")) ) {
    }
});
```